# Python - save multiple responses from multiple requests

Tags: python, rest

*I am pulling JSON data from an api and I am looking to pass in a different parameter for each request and save each response*

**My current code**

```
# create an empty list to store each account id 
accounts = []
##store in accounts list every id
for each in allAccounts['data']:
    accounts.append((each['id']))


#for each account , call a new account id for the url
for id in accounts:
    urlAccounts = 'https://example.somewebsite.ie:000/v12345/accounts/'+id+'/users'
```

I save a response and print out the values.

```
accountReq = requests.get(urlAccounts, headers=headers)
allUsers = accountReq.json()

for each in allUsers['data']:
    print(each['username']," " +each['first_name'])
```

This is fine and it works but I only store the first ID's response.

****How do I store the responses from all of the requests?
So I'm looking to send multiple requests where the ID changes every time and save each response essentially.****

I'm using python version 3.10.4 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code for this in case anyone stumbles across this.

```
# list of each api url to use
link =[]
#for every id in the accounts , create a new url link into the link list
for i in accounts:
    link.append('https://example.somewebsite.ie:000/v12345/accounts/'+i+'/users')

#create a list with all the different requests
accountReq = []
for i in link:
    accountReq.append(requests.get(i, headers=headers).json())

# write to a txt file
with open('masterSheet.txt', 'x') as f:
    #for every request
    for each in accountReq:
        #get each accounts data
        account = each['data']
        #for each accounts data
        #get each users email and names
        for data in account:
                sheet=(data['username']+" "+" ",data['first_name'],data['last_name'])
                f.write(str(sheet)+"\n")
```